# How can I match values in one file to ranges from another?

Tags: perl, awk

There are two input files, as the following lines show.

Columns 3 and 4 in `input1` hold a range (such as `1` to `78` in the first row)

Column 2 in `input2` holds a single position value (such `32` in the first row) which corresponds to one of the ranges in column in `input1`, and the corresponding value in column 2: in this case `B100002`.

I want to generate a file that contain the position, relative to the start of the range, for the every value in column 2 of file `input1`

For example, 358-344 + 1 = 15 is the relative position value for `B100043`

#### input1:

```
Scaffold_1      B100002        1       78
Scaffold_1      B100041        179     243
Scaffold_1      B100043        344     418
Scaffold_1      B100045        519     583
Scaffold_1      B100058        684     751
Scaffold_1      B100059        852     915
Scaffold_1      B100066        1016    1079
Scaffold_1      B100080        1180    1246
Scaffold_1      B100111        1347    1413
Scaffold_1      B100118        1514    1585
Scaffold_2      B123465        31531   31595
```

#### input2:

```
Scaffold_1      32
Scaffold_1      358
Scaffold_2      31533
```

#### Required output:

```
B100002      32
B100043      15
B123465      2
```

#### This is my solution

1. Change the format from `input1` to `input_1` and `input2` to `input_2` (tab separation)
2. Use software [bedtools](http://bedtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/content/tools/intersect.html) and awk to generate the output file that I want.

#### input_1:

```
Scaffold_1      .       B100002        1       78      .      .       .       .
Scaffold_1      .       B100041        179     243     .      .       .       .
Scaffold_1      .       B100043        344     418     .      .       .       .
Scaffold_1      .       B100045        519     583     .      .       .       .
Scaffold_1      .       B100058        684     751     .      .       .       .
Scaffold_1      .       B100059        852     915     .      .       .       .
Scaffold_1      .       B100066        1016    1079    .      .       .       .
Scaffold_1      .       B100080        1180    1246    .      .       .       .
Scaffold_1      .       B100111        1347    1413    .      .       .       .
Scaffold_1      .       B100118        1514    1585    .      .       .       .
Scaffold_1      .       B101068        9218    9290    .      .       .       .
Scaffold_2      .       B123465        31531   31595   .      .       .       .

input_2:
Scaffold_1      .       .      31         33       .       .       .       .
Scaffold_1      .       .      357        359      .       .       .       .
Scaffold_2      .       .      31532      31534    .       .       .       .


bedtools intersect -wb -a test2 -b test1 | awk '{print $12,($5-$13)}'
B100002 32
B100043 15
B123465 3
```

How can I use `awk` or `perl` to achieve my purpose? (I have to change file format when I use bedtools.)

Comment: @user6037276 Please note that I have had to reproduce your question here so that I could post my answer. I hope it helps

Comment: Instead of re-posting the same question, you can go to the [Close Vote Reviewers chatroom](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) and request reopen votes. When I've done that in the past, the question has been reopened within 5 minutes. I appreciate what you've done here, though.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: I considered that, but another five minutes' work on top of ten minutes translation and forty minutes writing a solution didn't go down too well tonight. Take a look at [*Answering suspended questions*](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326227/answering-suspended-questions).

Comment: wrt `If I ever notice that that question has been reopened then I will delete this copy and reproduce my answer there`: What are you going to do if the answer you [should] end up accepting isn't yours?

Comment: @EdMorton: I don't see a problem. What are you imagining?

Comment: @Borodin Someone posts a bright, shining solution to this question, the old question gets reopened so you copy your solution into the old question and delete this question and said bright, shining solution to the original question is gone from posterity. I didn't downvote this btw.

Comment: @EdMorton: I don't follow. Is this a complaint about me chasing points? I have updated the original question to improve the English, but I still can't post a solution there. That doesn't seem to be how SO wants to work. There is also a command-line solution as well as my own. Win all round?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37835435/the-original-how-can-i-match-values-in-one-file-to-ranges-from-another

Comment: @Borodin it's not a complaint about anything, I was simply asking what you're going to do with answers this question receives (other than your own) if/when the old question is reopened and you delete this question after duplicating your own answer under the old question - are you going to contact the other posters of answers to move their answers from here to the old question and wait for that to happen before you close this question or are you going to copy their answers into yours in the old question with some accreditation comment or do nothing or something else?

Comment: @EdMorton: Pretty much any of the above, depending how things pan out. I suspect the original one *won't* be reopened, and it may end up with this one being closed too. But I will do all I can to assign all credit that is due. Having raised this on meta, I now understand that pretty much the *only* difference with closed messages is that they may not receive answers. That's supposed to be a sanction against the author to encourage them to write better questions, but it hits answerers like me pretty hard when we come back after an hour's work and find the gate closed!

Comment: Fair enough, doesnt seem like there's any perfect way to handle it.

Comment: Please learn how to ask questions on SO

Comment: @AchalaYasasPiyarathna: What are you suggesting is wrong with the question?

Answer (score 6):

if the data file sizes are not huge, there is a simpler way

```
$ join input1 input2 | awk '$5<$4 && $3<$5 {print $2, $5-$3+1}'

B100002 32
B100043 15
B123465 3
```

Answer (score 0):

This Perl code seems to solve your problem

It is a common idiom: to load the entire dictionary in `input1.txt` into an in-memory data structure -- here `%data`, which is indexed by the scaffold ID -- and then process the object data to gather information from the dictionary

Assuming your `input1` isn't enormous this should work fine. It's impossible to key data structures on a range, so every candidate range must be checked to see if the index falls above the start and below the end

If there is a match then the ID is printed together with the result of the arithmetic to calculate the one-based relative index

Note that your required result for the entry `Scaffold_2      31533` should be 3 and not 2

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use autodie;

use Data::Dump;

my %data;
{
    open my $fh, '<', 'input1.txt';

    while ( <$fh> ) {
        next unless /\S/;
        my ($scaff, $code, $start, $end) = split;
        push @{ $data{$scaff} }, { start => $start, end => $end, code => $code };
    }
}

open my $fh, '<', 'input2.txt';

while ( <$fh> ) {

    my ($scaff, $index) = split;
    my $items = $data{$scaff} or die qq{No such scaffold "$scaff"};

    for my $item( @$items ) {

        next unless $index >= $item->{start} and $index <= $item->{end};

        printf "%s\t%d\n",
                $item->{code},
                $index - $item->{start} + 1;

        last
    }
}
```

#### output

```
B100002 32
B100043 15
B123465 3
```

Comment: I imagine the downvotes are political, which contravenes SO guidelines. Is there anything really wrong with my solution?

Comment: People are free to vote however they like, as long as it isn't targeted at a *user*. You may ask a question [on meta](//meta.stackoverflow.com) if you'd like.

Comment: @Undo: Thanks for your comment. I have posted questions on meta, and probably became infamous for them. The problem is that meta is populated by a tier of users who are entrenched with their idea of SO being right as it is. The proportion of people who post regular questions and answers who also write on meta must be tiny, yet SO professes to be a democracy. Hey ho. I'm sad but I must sleep. Best.